# Integral of $f(x,y)=\sin(x+y)$ on $R=\{(x,y):0\leq x, y\leq \frac{\pi}{2} \}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Integral of $f(x,y)=\sin(x+y)$ on $R=\{(x,y):0\leq x, y\leq \frac{\pi}{2} \}$

So I believe I should be evaluating $\int_0^x\int_y^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(x+y)dxdy$

which I find is equal to $\int_0^x -\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{2})+\cos(x+y)dx$
$=\int_0^1 \sin(x)+\cos(x+y)dx$

$=-\cos(x)-\cos(0)+\sin(x+y)-\sin(y)$

$=\sin(x+y)-\sin(y)-\cos(x)-1$

Does this seem correct? Mostly I was just unsure of how to deal with the bounds since every other integral I've done had strict upper and lower bounds.

Comment: Is the region for $$0\leq x,y\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$$ or for $$0\leq x\leq y\leq\frac{\pi}{2}~?$$

Comment: The first, $0\leq x,y\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Note that, technically, $R=\{(x,y):0\leq x, y\leq \frac{\pi}{2} \}=\{(x,y):0\leq x\text{ and } y\leq \frac{\pi}{2} \}$. You intended $R=\{(x,y):0\leq x\leq\frac{\pi}{2},0\leq y\leq \frac{\pi}{2} \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral you should be computing is $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x+y)dxdy$$ Since the region over which you're integrating is just $$R=\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]^2.$$ This integral is easier, and can be computed using, for instance, that the antiderivative of $\sin(x+y)$ with respect to $x$ is just $-\cos(x+y)$.

Comment: Oh see I guess my interpretation is $x\geq 0$ and $y\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: So if you want $x\geq 0$ and $y\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$, then the integral is $$\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{\pi/2}\sin(x+y)dydx$$